# BSOD while video conferencing

Tags: windows, bsod, crash, conferencing

My laptop, Asus VivoBook X542U, Windows 10 Pro, crashes (BSOD) while I video conference.
This happens on Zoom and also on Microsoft Teams.
Sometimes it happens the minute I enter the meeting. Other times it doesn't crash at all. But usually, it crashes after 20-30 minutes into the meeting.

I was told I should use WinDbg to analyze the dump file. So I ran it, but I don't understand the error log. I've uploaded it to [here](https://gofile.io/d/e2s8KC). Can anyone give me a hint to the root of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's the Asus AI Charger. I would disable it and see if that solves your issue.

To disable it:

1. Press Ctrl + Shift + Esc to open Task Manager
2. Click on the Startup Tab
3. See if Asus AI charger is listed there
4. If it is, select it and click 'Disable'
5. Close Task Manager
6. Restart your PC

If the issue resolves, you can try looking for a driver update for it. Otherwise I would just uninstall it from the Control Panel.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I don't see anything related to charging in the Startup Tab. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: @Itai is it listed in task manager at all? Open it up and then check the processes and look for either AI Charger or possibly Asus Suite Manager. You could also check Control Panel for Asus Suite Manager or AI Charger.

Comment: I see other Asus stuff in the Control Panel, not exactly what you wrote. Here is a screenshot of what I see there (that seems relevant).
https://i.postimg.cc/13QWw8Rm/super-user.jpg

Comment: @Itai ASUS USB Charger Plus would probably be the one, based off of what read, but I don't know for certain. It won't hurt to remove it so I would try it.

Comment: I've removed it. I Will test it in the coming days and update here if it resolved the issue. Thank you